# Jquery .wrapAll problem

Tags: jquery, xml, wrapall

I'm parsing an xml file and I want to wrap children divs into a div called "new":

I have something similar to below:

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
 $(xml).find("hotel").each(function()
 {
 $('<div class="wrapme"></div>').html($(this).find("hotel_name").text()).appendTo('#foo');
 });
}
$('.wrapme').wrapAll('<div class="group" />');

// output: not working, it doesn't enclose my wrapme divs into Group
```

Anyone knows the reason ?

Appreciate your help guys!!

The problem is that .wrapAll doesn't seem to work in this particular cases

Answer (score 1):

The call to `wrapAll` is outside the function, so that will only run once when the javascript file is loaded. Is that what you meant to do?

Also, I'm not sure that wrapAll accepts self-closing elements like that. You might need to use `<div></div>`.